# Installing Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Specs: XCode 4.3.2, Mac OS X 10.7.3, RVM 1.12.3 (stable).

I really need help with this so anything is appreciated.

I installed Ruby 1.8.7, then needed to update to 1.9.3 so I found RVM. I installed RVM and then tried to update and this is the result:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/myname/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/myname/.rvm/src
Error running 'tar xmzf /Users/myname/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/myname/.rvm/src ', please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/extract.log
Configuring yaml in /Users/myname/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure
    --prefix="/Users/myname/.rvm/usr" ', please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/configure.log Compiling yaml in /Users/myname/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/make.log

Database file /Users/myname/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125,
this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125
- #fetching ruby-1.9.3-p125
- #extracted to /Users/myname/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 (already extracted) ruby-1.9.3-p125
- #configuring Error running ' ./configure
    --prefix=/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/myname/.rvm/usr ',

please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ls: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/*/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the log files referenced as it instructs you to?

Comment: Did you install rvm with sudo?

Comment: I installed rvm with curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable, I am just learning Ruby, like this is my 3rd day, so I dont think many of the files will make sense to me. Can I post them here and you guys could help?

Comment: I navigated to /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies, but when I ls the rubies file is empty..

Answer (score 3):

please install [osx-gcc-installer 10.7](https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.7-v2.pkg)

read and follow the requirements:

```
rvm requirements
```

and finally reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) with ruby-build to manage your rubies.

It's much simpler than rvm and less magical.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this blog and install any version of ruby

```
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/
```

Comment: this tutorial is a bit outdated